# How to prevent class instantiation with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I had an interview question that asked roughly the following: with dependency injection, how do you prevent all of the classes from being instantiated? What if you only want a few, but not all? There are good reasons, they said, for example to avoid them all being in memory at the same time...

I've tried to research this question but it's hard to even figure out the best search term is. And no answers could I find.

Comment: The supposed question doesn't make sense. There is no DI container that instantiates "all classes" so that they are all "in memory at the same time". A container instantiates only what it is asked for, thus a valid although meaningless answer could be "a way to prevent a container from creating instances is not to ask it for instances". I guess we need then more that you remembered to suggest a better answer.

Comment: I don't know of a better way to ask this question. It may have been a trick question at an interview. I don't know. I hate that it's broad, that it's on hold, etc. I hate getting downvoted with no suggestion as to how I could make this question better, less broad. @WiktorZychla - thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I wasn't one who downvoted you, actually I upvoted you because I don't believe your questions deserves to be downvoted. As for suggestions - I tried to explain to you that what you asked as the question doesn't make sense. So either the question was somehow different (so that actual answer is possible) or you got an invalid question asked by someone who doesn't know what they are asking about. Even the answer you accepted states that it doesn't make sense to ask for "instantiation prevention" as there is no such thing in DI.

Comment: And, in my opinion you really expect too much from the community. Do you really believe people read between the lines and try to come up with all possible answers to all possible ways to correct your question and you just will be like "nope, this answer doesn't answer my question because I really mean something else but I am not sure what"? My personal opinion is that they tried to ask you about container lifetime policies but since you were "caught off guard" you can't repeat the question correctly enough to be sure this is what they meant.

Comment: These are fair criticisms. It seems that I didn't even know enough about my question to even ask a good question, but I didn't know my question was bad to start with. Clearly I have more learning to do about this topic. Thank you again for helping me understand where I'm falling short. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to create it with a constructor and instantiate a single  class based on a flag or switch. Here is a simple example that shows that only a single `OtherClass` or `OtherClass2` would be instantiated.

I would like to add however that it isn't really Dependency Injection that allows the prevention of instantiation. You could get rid of the DI and have tightly coupled classes and still have a single instance of a class. So maybe I am not understanding the question correctly or maybe the interviewer asked it in a different context/manner?

```
class AppStart
{
    OneClass One;
    int _whatToCreate = 0;

    public int WhatToCreate
    {
        get { return _whatToCreate; }
        set { _whatToCreate = value; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (_whatToCreate > 0)
        {
            One = new OneClass(new OtherClass());
        }
        else
        {
            One = new OneClass(new OtherClass2());
        }

        One.PerformSomething();
    }
}

class OneClass
{
    IDoSomething _doSomething;

    public OneClass(IDoSomething doSomething)
    {
        _doSomething = doSomething;
    }

    public void PerformSomething()
    {
        _doSomething.DoSomething();
    }
}

class OtherClass : IDoSomething
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class OtherClass2 : IDoSomething
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

interface IDoSomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I may not remember all of the details of this, or I was caught off guard by the question, or ... something. But this is a good answer, since it is reflective of my general thinking about this anyway. Thanks!